# Select interaction 'select' event

Tags: openlayers-3

I have created a select interaction for my ol3 map and attached a select event handler.

```
selectInteraction = new ol.interaction.Select({
    ...
});

selectInteraction.on('select', function (evt) {
    ???;
});
```

How do I interrogate 'evt' to determine:

- Which feature was clicked to fire the event?
- The ID and other attributes of this feature?
- Whether the feature was selected or deselected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `select` event emitted by the `ol.SelectInteraction` is documented [here](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.interaction.SelectEvent.html).

As you can see, `evt.selected` will be an array of all features that were just selected. It will not contain already selected features which are kept selected when clicking a new feature while the `addCondition` is true. These are the clicked features that were not already selected and matched the filters to be included in the selection.

Likewise, `evt.deselected` will contain any features that were just deselected.

You can get the ID and properties of each feature with:

```
var featureID = feature.getId()
var properties = feature.getProperties()
var someSpecificProperty = feature.get("property-name")
```

See the docs for [`ol.Feature`](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.Feature.html) for more info on the feature and it's attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some items that should help you.. evt.selected gets you the features that are selected.  This example is on a clustered layer and you can use the `get` function on features selected to retrieve properties from the object selected.  If you don't know properties available to you then use `console.dir(evt)` to examine the object using the console.

```
   selectInteraction.on('select', function(evt){
      var coord = evt.mapBrowserEvent.coordinate;
      var selItems = evt.selected;
      var sellength = selItems.length;
      var rptFrame = parent.window.frames["rptframe"];
      for (var i = 0; i < sellength; i++) {
        var label = selItems[i].get('l');
        var url = selItems[i].get('url');
        if (url) {
          rptFrame.location.href = url;
        } else {
          var feaObj = selItems[i].get('features');
        if (feaObj.length == 1) {
           url = feaObj[0].get('url');
           rptFrame.location.href = url;
        } else {
          writeMultiSelect(rptFrame,selItems);
        }
      }
    }
  });
```